# Run 1920X1200 HiDPI on a 13" MBP Retina - High Sierra?

Tags: display, macbook, macbook-pro, macbook-pro-retina, macos-highsierra

I would like to run 1920X1200 HiDPI on a my 13" MBP Retina.

Before upgrading to High Sierra I was able to do that either by manually adding the 3840x2400 resolution by following the tutorial in the link below. But the /System/Library/Displays/**Overrides/** folder does not seem to be present on High Sierra:

https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/2ia242/enabling_1920_x_1200_hidpi_resolution_on_the_13/

As an alternativ to the manual method above I could add it SwitchResX in the "Custom Resolutions"-section. But when I add the resolution it just says "Not installed".

https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-to-run-1920x1200-hidpi-on-a-13-macbook-pro-retina.1720285/

Answer (score 1):

Some free solutions:

1. EasyRes app from Mac AppStore
2. ResXtreme.app

Answer (score 0):

..figured it out myself. Once I registered SwitchResX I got "rid" of the "Not installed", and now it works perfectly.